# Excel sets wrong currency after explicit numberFormat conversion

Tags: excel, vba, currency

I have the following line(s) of code:

```
With new_pivot_table.PivotFields( _
    "Count of Weighted Parameter")
    .Caption = "Sum of Weighted Parameter"
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
End With
```

But my Excel sheet displays the currencies in €. Why is Excel showing € instead of $? Does the currency depend on the location where I am currently sitting (i.e. set by any Windows services automatically) or is my syntax wrong? How can I enforce that this column(s) are displayed in $$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this little tutorial for change the currencies to Euros. I suppose that is the same method to change to Dollars.

http://www.howtogeek.com/240216/how-to-change-windows-default-currency-from-dollars-to-euros/

Follow this steps (Only in Windows):

- Search "Change the way currency is displayed"
- Click on "Additional settings".
- Select "Currency" tab.
- Select the currency symbol that you want in "Currency symbol" list.
- Apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it.